# dealing with multiple directories and schedules spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a set of schedules defined in my spring `application.yml` file as follows:

```
reports:
    reportPaths:
        11: "\\\\path\\pnl\\"
        10: "\\\\path\\balance\\"

schedule-1:
    description: Deliver pnl files
    report: 11
    format: PDF
    cron: '0 00 17* * *'

schedule-2:
    description: Deliver balance sheet files
    report: 10
    format: PDF
    cron: '0 00 16* * *'
```

The different file types are created on the server at different times. My application wants to sftp the reports as per the **cron** schedules.

I register and schedule the jobs as follows:

```
threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(new Job(schedule), new CronTrigger(environment.getProperty(schedule + ".cron")));
```

Job Class:

```
public class Job implements Runnable {


    private String job;

    public ScheduledJobRouter(String job) {
        this.job= job;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("Running Report job'{}' ({})", job);
    }
}
```

My question is, as I am dealing with **multiple directories** for each of the report type I send to subscribers, how can I initiate the integration workflow based on the schedules with `spring-integration`. For example, at the schedule time of `16:00 hrs:.`
FileReadingMessageSource`  reads directory for report 10

at 17:00 hrs, `FileReadingMessageSource`  reads directory for report 11.

How can I initialise the `FileReadingMessageSource` for the multiple directories I am dealing with at scheduled times. Do I have to define multiple beans for each report directories I am dealing with?

Perhaps, there is a better alternative this framework provides to handle such case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [smart poller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers) to reconfigure the `MessageSource` before or after each poll.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46409658Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46409658Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("reports.reportPaths.10")
    private String ten;

    @Value("reports.reportPaths.11")
    private String eleven;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "foo", poller = @Poller("poller"))
    public MessageSource<File> frms() {
        new File(this.ten).mkdirs();
        new File(this.eleven).mkdirs();
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(new File(this.ten));
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
        poller.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
        poller.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(advice()));
        return poller;
    }

    public AbstractMessageSourceAdvice advice() {
        return new AbstractMessageSourceAdvice() {

            private volatile boolean swap;

            @Override
            public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
                File directory = new File(this.swap ? eleven : ten);
                ((FileReadingMessageSource) source).setDirectory(directory);
                swap = !swap;
                System.out.println("Polling " + directory);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
                return result;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

If you are using XML configuration, add the advice chain to the `<poller/>`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a good example you are aware of demonstrating the concept?

Comment: Thank you for the example. As I am dealing with about 5/6 report types which all get generated at different times, is it possible to initialise the  'Job' task in my example let's say with all the config properties e.g file input directory, file pattern etc and then initialise the FRMS from run() method? Just not sure if that is possible so for each task adapter is defined and to same channel

Comment: Oh; I missed the fact you have different cron schedules for each one; and that you are scheduling manually rather than using a poller. Since these are one-shot crons (daily), it's not really clear you are getting much benefit from using the FRMS at all.

Comment: I thought of using FRMS to publish the files as Messages to PublishSubscribeChannel so that I can have JDBC and SFTP adapters connected to it, so files sent for each schedules and metadata written to DB. Any better approach ?

Comment: Then I am confused as to why you are running your own scheduler. The FRMS doesn't publish to a channel, the`SourcePollingChannelAdapter` does.